# I am trying to initialize a glogal structure(trie_node) as the head of a trie in my main function and am getting memory allocation problems

Tags: c, struct, malloc

Basically when i try to initialize it in main i get this from valgrind

````
==4262==    at 0x109730: main (in /home/raf/os/domaci4/main)
==4262==  Address 0x544c210 is 0 bytes after a block of size 464 alloc'd
==4262==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4262==    by 0x1096D3: main (in /home/raf/os/domaci4/main)
==4262== 
``` ```

typedef struct trie_node
{
    char c;
    int term;
    int subwords;
    struct trie_node *parent;
    struct trie_node *children[LETTERS];
}trie_node;
````

Here is how i wrote it as global
 `struct trie_node *head;`

And here i try to allocate the memory and set everything to 0.

```
    head = (trie_node*) malloc(sizeof(struct trie_node));
    head->term = 0;
    head->parent = NULL;
    head->subwords = 0;
    head->c = NULL;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_WORD_LEN; i++)
    {
        head->children[i] = NULL;
    }
```

Im trying to figure out what exactly is the problem. Any help would be really appreciated!

```
==4810==    at 0x10974B: main (in /home/raf/os/domaci4/main)
==4810==  Address 0x544c568 is 0 bytes after a block of size 232 alloc'd
==4810==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4810==    by 0x1096EE: main (in /home/raf/os/domaci4/main)
==4810== 

valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:280 (mk_plain_bszB): Assertion 'bszB != 0' failed.
valgrind: This is probably caused by your program erroneously writing past the
end of a heap block and corrupting heap metadata.  If you fix any
invalid writes reported by Memcheck, this assertion failure will
probably go away.  Please try that before reporting this as a bug.


host stacktrace:
==4810==    at 0x5804417A: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==4810==    by 0x58044294: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==4810==    by 0x58044419: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==4810==    by 0x580531AC: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==4810==    by 0x5800BA44: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==4810==    by 0x5800BC26: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==4810==    by 0x5809F705: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==4810==    by 0x580AECD0: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 4810)
==4810==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4810==    by 0x50D918B: _IO_file_doallocate (filedoalloc.c:101)
==4810==    by 0x50E9378: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:365)
==4810==    by 0x50E8497: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:759)
==4810==    by 0x50E69EC: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1266)
==4810==    by 0x50DBA8E: puts (ioputs.c:40)
==4810==    by 0x10984D: main (in /home/raf/os/domaci4/main)
```

Here is the whole valgrind message.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char stopThread[10] = "\t";
    char add[10] = "_add_";
    char stop[10] = "_stop_";
    char file[50];
    char abs[100] = "/home/raf/os/domaci4/";
    char temp[100];
    char temp2[50];
    int j = 1;

    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    pthread_t thread3;
    pthread_t thread4;
    pthread_t thread5;

    head =  malloc(sizeof(trie_node));
    head->term = 0;
    head->parent = NULL;
    head->subwords = 0;
    head->c = NULL;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_WORD_LEN; i++)
    {
        head->children[i] = NULL;
    }



    char nesto[50];

    //char unos[50];
    char unos[200];
    while(1)
    {   
        //printf("Unesite komandu\n");
        scanf("%s", &unos);


        if(strcmp(unos, add) == 0){
            scanf("%s", &unos);
            strcpy(temp, unos);
            DIR *directory = NULL;

                //printf("Open success\n");
                /*
                if(j == 1){
                    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, scanner_work, &temp);
                }
                j++;
                */
                //pthread_t threads[j] = (pthread_t*) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));


                }

        /*
        if(strcmp(unos, stopThread) == 0){
            pthread_cancel(thread1);
        }
        */
        if(strcmp(unos, stop) == 0){
            printf("Izlaz iz sistema\n");
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0;


}
```

This is the whole main function but the program wont even start.

Comment: You do not test whether the allocation was successful before attempting to use the allocated space.  Also, it is poor style to cast the return value of `malloc()` in C, and doing so can have the effect of masking one of the possible problems that could explain the misbehavior.  Also, it is suspicious that you dimension `children` for `LETTERS` elements, but initialize `MAX_WORD_LEN` elements.  Overall, however, we need a [mre] that demonstrates the problem to say definitively what the problem is.

Comment: You cut off the important part of the valgrind error message where it tells you what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your code fragment doesn't have enough detail to what the real problem is.

But, here's some trie code I've had lying around. It should give you some ideas on how to fix your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define LETTERS     26
typedef struct trie trie_t;
struct trie {
    int trie_let;                               // letter
    int trie_eow;                               // 1=end-of-word

    trie_t *trie_par;                           // pointer to parent
    trie_t *trie_cld[LETTERS];                  // children
};

trie_t *root;
#define TRIEPRT_MAX     10000
char trieprt_buf[TRIEPRT_MAX + 1];

// triefind -- find matching child trie based on id
trie_t *
triefind(trie_t *par,int let)
{
    int cldidx;
    trie_t *cld;
    trie_t *match;

    match = NULL;

    for (cldidx = 0;  cldidx < LETTERS;  ++cldidx) {
        cld = par->trie_cld[cldidx];

        // skip empty slot
        // NOTE: this will probably never happen based on trieattach
        if (cld == NULL)
            continue;

        if (cld->trie_let == let) {
            match = cld;
            break;
        }
    }

    return match;
}

// trienew -- get new trie
trie_t *
trienew(int let)
{
    trie_t *trie;

    trie = calloc(1,sizeof(trie_t));
    trie->trie_let = let;

    return trie;
}

// trieattach -- attach new child trie
trie_t *
trieattach(trie_t *par,int let)
{
    trie_t *cld;

    // allocate new trie
    cld = trienew(let);

    // cross-link parent and child
    cld->trie_par = par;
    par->trie_cld[let] = cld;

    return cld;
}

// triefindx -- find matching child trie (create new trie if none found)
trie_t *
triefindx(trie_t *par,int let)
{
    trie_t *cld;

    // find existing trie
    cld = triefind(par,let);

    // create new trie if it doesn't already exist
    if (cld == NULL)
        cld = trieattach(par,let);

    return cld;
}

// trieword -- add an entire word
void
trieword(const char *str)
{
    int chr;
    trie_t *trie;
    int nxt;

    trie = root;
    for (chr = *str++;  chr != 0;  chr = nxt) {
        nxt = *str++;

        chr = toupper(chr);

        trie = triefindx(trie,chr - 'A');

        // mark end-of-word
        if (nxt == 0)
            trie->trie_eow = 1;
    }
}

// trieprtone -- print single word
void
trieprtone(trie_t *cur)
{
    char *ptr;
    int chr;

    ptr = &trieprt_buf[TRIEPRT_MAX];
    *--ptr = 0;

    // NOTE: the root trie is a dummy and has the only negative value
    for (trie_t *par = cur;  par != NULL;  par = par->trie_par) {
        chr = par->trie_let;
        if (chr < 0)
            break;
        *--ptr = chr + 'A';
    }

    printf("trieprtont: '%s'\n",ptr);
}

// trieprtall -- print all trie elements
void
trieprtall(trie_t *par)
{
    trie_t *cld;

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < LETTERS;  ++idx) {
        cld = par->trie_cld[idx];
        if (cld == NULL)
            continue;

        if (cld->trie_eow)
            trieprtone(cld);

        trieprtall(cld);
    }
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    FILE *fi;
    char *file;
    char *bp;
    char *cp;
    char delims[256];
    char buf[10000];

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    // NOTE: this source file makes a good test input
    if (argc > 0)
        file = argv[0];
    else
        file = "wordlist.txt";

    fi = fopen(file,"r");
    if (fi == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"unable to open '%s' -- %s\n",file,strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    root = trienew(-1);

    cp = delims;
    for (int chr = 1;  chr < 0x7F;  ++chr) {
        if (isalpha(chr))
            continue;
        *cp++ = chr;
    }
    *cp = 0;

    while (1) {
        cp = fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fi);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        bp = buf;
        while (1) {
            cp = strtok(bp,delims);
            if (cp == NULL)
                break;

            bp = NULL;

            trieword(cp);
        }
    }

    fclose(fi);

    trieprtall(root);

    return 0;
}
```