# Segmentation Core Dumped in Pset 5 CS50

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, cs50

I currently am working on PSET5 speller for CS50. I am trying to implement hash tables and tries together to load dictionary. The problem is it keeps showing Segmentation Fault and I can't seem to find what's wrong. Is there an error on my code or it just wont simply work?

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    bool is_word;
    struct node *children[26];
}
node;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 71;

// Hash table
node *table[N];



//Counts words
int word_count = 0;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO: Improve this hash function

    return tolower(word[0]) - 'a';
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    for (int z = 0; z<71; z++) {
        table[z] = malloc(sizeof(node));
        for (int i = 0; i<26; i++) {
            table[z]->children[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", dictionary);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }
    int index = 0;
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    char c;

    while (fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, file)) {
        if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0)) {
            word[index] = c;
            index++;
        }

        else if (index>0) {
            word[index] = '\0';
            word_count +=1;
            int hashword = hash(word);
            node *cursor = table[hashword];
            for (int j = 0; j<index; j++) {
                int letterindex = tolower(word[j]) - 'a';
                if (cursor->children[letterindex] == NULL) {
                    node *new = malloc(sizeof(node));
                    if (new == NULL) {
                        printf("ERROR NULL!");
                        return 0;
                    }
                    new->is_word = false;
                    for (int k = 0; k<26; k++) {
                        new->children[k] = NULL;
                    }
                    cursor->children[letterindex] = new;

                }
                cursor = cursor->children[letterindex];

            }
            cursor->is_word = true;

            index = 0;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    return word_count;
}

void unloader(node* current)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (current->children[i] != NULL)
        {
            unloader(current->children[i]);
        }
    }
    free(current);
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        if (table[i] != NULL) {
            unloader(table[i]);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example, cutting out the file reading part?

Comment: *`node *new = malloc(sizeof(node));`* `new` could be `NULL`.

Comment: Can the element of my hash table not be tries?

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to use both a hash table and a trie. You can do it but there is no reason to.

Comment: What kind of debugging have you done? What did you learn from it?

Comment: For a trie node you probably need a member for the current character (e.g. `int curchar;`)

Comment: I looks like load doesn't do anything. Upon reading the first letter from the dictionary, it returns `true` because `index` is 0. Use a debugger, breakpoint at `if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0))` and see where it goes from there.

Comment: The cs50 speller problem is usually done with a hash table of linked lists. See my answer: [cs50 pset5 Speller optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71316468/5382650) For a general trie implementation, see my answer: [I am trying to initialize a glogal structure(trie_node) as the head of a trie in my main function and am getting memory allocation problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62236036/5382650)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
        if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0)) {
            word[index] = c;
            index++;
        }
```

The code grants "letter status" to a single apostrophe (0x27) (eg: "`don't`")

There are only 26 letters in the alphabet and that's the number of `children` at each node.

Later:

```
            int letterindex = tolower(word[j]) - 'a';
```

0x27 (`'\''`) - 0x61 (`'a'`) ==> (a negative index)

So any use of `cursor->children[letterindex]` will invoke UB...

There's probably more, but this is likely one major bug.

This would probably have been more obvious and avoided if the `tolower()` operation was not hidden in the complexities of growing the Trie. Perhaps this code can be salvaged if a translation is performed:

```
        if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0)) {
            word[index] = (c == '\'') ? 'z' + 1 : tolower( c ); 
            index++;
        }
```

Expand the `struct node *children[26];` to `...[27]`. Then, apply this costly translation to every operation on every character when performing lookups. Oh, and correct every instance of the *magic number* `26` found throughout the code. Big job...

---

Consider the memory requirements of a Trie to store "*antidisestablishmentarianism*". 27 pointers @ 8 bytes each for **each** of the 28 nodes. While "*anti...*" is a common prefix string, is it worth expending 5Kb (27*(28-4)*8) needed to store this one long word?

---

Aside: The OP asks: "*... or it just wont simply work?*", forming a nice reflection on the significance of the humble single apostrophe. Curious, too, that its ASCII value in hex is 0x27; the wannabe 27th letter in the allowable collection.